# how to implement single sign on using DotNetOpenAuth?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dotnetopenauth, single-sign-on

Hi 
I am having the asp.net MVC site. I want to implement Single sign on on my site using DotNetOpenAuth. I have downloaded its library from [here](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) 
But could not understand how to start implementation. I tried Jenrain also, infact I was able to logging in by jenrain , but its C# class not providing me the logged in user information to start the session and all...So i came across at dotnetopenauth but not getting right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to implement OpenID using the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) library and create a one-to-many relationship between your `User` table and a newly created `User_OpenID` table.

[Scot Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx) has a good basic article or try a [more in depth overview](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe)

Comment: Yes, it is nice theory , it must be bit practical .